# What is the most stable way to use React, ECMAscript 6, and Gulp?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, gulp

I find it easy to use any two of three together but all in one gulp task is such a tall task.

What are the node packages to streamline this process?

Comment: drop gulp, add webpack and use only scripts from `package.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gulp-browserify can help build your code for you (lots of tutorials out there). That said I agree that dropping gulp altogether in favor of webpack is probably the way to go - also lots of tutorials (specifically for React, too) out there on how to get that up and running.